# Mapping influenced my return key to toggle the syntastic check mode

Tags: key-bindings

I've mapped control-m to start the Syntastic check mode (Active/Passive)

```
nnoremap <c-m> :SyntasticToggleMode<Cr>
```

But in normal mode, when I tap the return key, it also toggles the mode. When removing the mapping line above, the problem is off. Any clue of that?

Thanks

Comment: The keycode of the return key is `^M` just like `<c-m>` See the `Remember that some key combinations are equivalent` in the duplicate question.

Comment: For more information on *why* CTRL-M and `Return` equivalent, see [Terminals are Weird](https://catern.com/posts/terminal_quirks.html), and if you're wondering why CTRL-M and `Return` are *still* equivalent, see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/2bp9UdfZ63M/sajb9KM0pNYJ) on the vim_dev list.